# can someone explain this seemingly weird assignment `{key=value} = argument`

Tags: javascript, class, subclass

Context: this is a task in a [javascript tutorial](https://javascript.info/class-inheritance#extended-clock). The code is supposed to generate a subclass `ExtendedClock` of `Clock` that allows the console to show the current time in a customized interval of time.

```
Class Clock {
  constructor({ template }) {
    this._template = template;
  }

  _render() {
    let date = new Date();

    let hours = date.getHours();
    if (hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;

    let mins = date.getMinutes();
    if (mins < 10) min = '0' + mins;

    let secs = date.getSeconds();
    if (secs < 10) secs = '0' + secs;

    let output = this._template
      .replace('h', hours)
      .replace('m', mins)
      .replace('s', secs);

    console.log(output);
  }

  stop() {
    clearInterval(this._timer);
  }

  start() {
    this._render();
    this._timer = setInterval(() => this._render(), 1000);
  }
}
```

Here comes the weird line in solution given in the tutorial:

```
class ExtendedClock extends Clock {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    let { precision=1000 } = options;  // what is this?
    this._precision = precision;
  }

  start() {
    this._render();
    this._timer = setInterval(() => this._render(), this._precision);
```

}
};
Another problem: My code is the following one. Why doesn't this work?

```
class ExtendedClock extends Clock {
  constructor({template, precision = 1000}) {
    super({template})
    this._precision = precision
  }

  start() {
    super.start()
    this._timer = setInterval(() => this._render(), this._precision)
  }
}
```

Comment: That weird line is destructuring in JavaScript, it means options will be an js Object and if there is key ( precision ) then its value will be assigned to precision variable else precision will be equal to 1000

Comment: I guess your solution doesnt work as expected as it starts two timers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's object destructuring syntax with a default value. If the object you're destructuring contains a `precision` key, that value will be used, but if it does not, `1000` will be used.

If the key exists, its value will be used:

```
const options = { precision: 800 };
const { precision = 1000 } = options;
console.log(precision); // logs 800
```

but if the key does not exist, the default value will be used:

```
const options = {};
const { precision = 1000 } = options;
console.log(precision); // logs 1000
```

---

Your code probably doesn't work because when you call `super.start()`, the superclass starts a loop with

```
setInterval(() => this._render(), 1000);
```

Your code starts a loop after this is called, but both loops are now running, causing the render function to be called every 1000ms by the superclass's `setInterval`, and then also separately every `precision`ms by your subclass's loop.

Instead of calling `super.start()` at the beginning of your loop, try just calling `this._render()`.

Answer (score 1):

this weird code is just a handy way to overwrite the default value if there is a Property for it.

```
let options = { precision: 999, template: 'h:m:s' };
let { precision = 1000 } = options; // precision === 999

let options = { template: 'h:m:s' };
let { precision = 1000 } = options; // precision === 1000
```

For the second issue I would need some more input. Which error do you get?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't get any error message, but the line `this._timer = setInterval(() => this._render(), this._precision)` isn't getting executed so the clock won't be printed out every 10000ms. Instead, it still shows up every 1000ms.