# Overriding function named params in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function lookupRecord2({value1 = "blue", value2 = 7}) {
        console.log('theValues');
        console.log(value1);
        console.log(value2);
}

lookupRecord2( { value1: 'pink', value2: 9 } );
```

I've read that Javascript doesn't allow for named parameters so I'm confused how the above code works. What is happening here that's allowing me to override the params?

I think what's confusing is that the params are assigned with "=" whereas the object I'm passing uses ":" ...

ADDED:

I know this is a form of destructuring, but I still can't make sense of it b/c it's in the function declaration.

Comment: Looks like destructured assignment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578167/es6-object-destructuring-default-parameters?noredirect=1&lq=1 ?

Comment: Thank you, I found examples like this but it has a {} = {} declaration, which seems different.

Comment: Perhaps this one. [javascript - can someone explain this seemingly weird assignment `{key=value} = argument` - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801891/can-someone-explain-this-seemingly-weird-assignment-key-value-argument?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thank you, that post led me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578167/es6-object-destructuring-default-parameters ... which answers the question! Big help!

Answer (score 0):

```
function des({ a = 1, b = 2 } = {}) {
        console.log(a);
        console.log(b);
}

des();
```

This is a destructing syntax where we're able to pass default values.
It works everywhere, not just in function declarations.

```
{ a = 1, b = 2 } = { b:3 }
// assigns 1 to "a" and because "b" already exists, "b" is 3
```

MORE INFO HERE: [can someone explain this seemingly weird assignment `{key=value} = argument`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801891/can-someone-explain-this-seemingly-weird-assignment-key-value-argument?noredirect=1&lq=1)